# How to use Identity Server with Xamarin.Forms and a Web API

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I'm building a Xamarin.Forms app for Android and IOS and would like to use Identity Server for the Authentication/Authorization.

The Identity Server would use Local accounts and External Providers (ex. Google etc.).
But the problem is, that I'm a bit confused about the flow of it all.

Without the Identity Server and user profile, i would normally have the Xamarin.Forms app, call an Web API for data and then display that data in the app, but now i would like to add user profiles to this, so you can log in and you can have data specific for your profile.
But how/where would i add the Identity Server into this, when right now the app is calling my Web API for data and without any user profiles.

I'm thinking that the app would call the Identity Server, then you might pick External Provider, you log in and it returns a Token to the app and then you would save that token?
And when you want data specific to your user, you send your Token to the Web API and then the Web API returns the data specific to your token, is that right?

I hope all of this makes sense.

[image: Picture of the current flow...]

### **EDIT:**

Now i figured out that the flow should be as explained in the picture below, as far as i understand.
So the App Server is our Web API.
[image: Picture of flow]

But how would you then get the claims (like username, firstname, lastname) down? And would it be stored in the app, when you first login or should it somehow be retrieved from the server everytime the app opens?

Comment: Are you referring to something like Authenticator:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/web-authenticator?tabs=android?

Comment: Hi @ColeX-MSFT I think it is not exactly that, but some of it could be used. I figured out that the flow probably should be like the new picture i added in the post. But now I'm a bit confused on the flow of the claims (like Username, Firstname... etc.). Like would you get it on the first login and then store it in the app or would you get it from the IdentityServer or Web API each time the app opens? And how is this done correctly? :)

Comment: Do you want to use [ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) or [IdentityServer](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)? Identity allows you to setup in-web-app authentication, supporting external logins (microsoft, google, facebook, twitter, github). IdentityServer allows you to provide a single-sign-on experience for all your web applications, using your own code. I'd personally try to avoid IdentityServer and stick to Identity only, since it'll probably end support soon.